# How to properly format these dates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Hello I have dates like this:
Tue, 07 Aug 2012 10:38:49 +0000

And what I want is if it's today to display only the hours: 10:38

If it was yesterday to display: Yesterday, 10:38

If it was last month to display: Wed,07 July, 10:38

You get that idea. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got any code that is not working? Or do you simply expect people to code for you? Do you have the dates in a NSString? Or are you storing them as NSDate objects?

Comment: I don't have an idea how to do it. I don't want you or anyone to code it for me. I just want an idea. I am storing them in NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the developer documentation.

More specifically look at `NSDateComponent` and `NSDate`

Answer (score 1):

```
    // <strong>Output ->  Date: 10/29/2008 08:29PM</strong>    
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
 [dateFormat release];
```